# import renders statement throws "No such module" error

Tags: python, jupyter, pca

I am trying to run PCA on my dataset. I came across a tutorial by Ritchie Ng: https://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-project-customer-segments/ 
and i am trying to recreate it on my dataset. However, the blog uses a package called "renders" which i am unable to find in Anaconda. How and where do i get and enable this package from? I have searched for this package in Anaconda navigator and google but i cant seem to find it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's the link to 'renders', as provided in the tutorial:

https://github.com/ritchieng/machine-learning-nanodegree/tree/master/unsupervised_learning/customer_segments

Comment: Thank you @piotrek!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have module file in directory.

> Module: A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py
>   appended.

Read more: [Python Tutorial - Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)